# How to pass two different templates into one directive and let the directive decide showing which one over time?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am building a Expand/ Collapse button with Angular2 and I will reuse this directive over different pages with different templates and UI.

After searching I still can't find the correct way to make it works.

`<ng-content />`? `<template />`? `TemplateRef`? How to do it correctly?

Comment: <ng-content></ng-content>

Comment: Yup, I agree... ng-content sounds like the way to go. Here's a good article that explains multiple transclusion with selectors: https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content

Answer (score 0):

You can create two variables in component and pass html code to it, after interpolate to string.

Another option is that you can make two components, pass appropiate templates to components and using ngIf to display just one component in a time. Should be easier if you will use @Input() and @Output() to manipulate DOM between components